# How to import site package's module instead of one in current directory that has the same name (python 3.x)?

Tags: python, pandas, import, pycharm, site-packages

I am heavy user of the pandas library. 
In order to keep useful custom made helper functions related to pandas library, I decided to create a custom project (my_proj) and a module pandas.py in it. 
Now I am developing another custom module related to ssh protocol in the same project.

Modules are created with pycharm. Structure of the project is as follows:

```
my_proj/src/my_proj/pandas.py
my_proj/src/my_proj/ssh.py
```

Everythin is OK and works properly. When I want to use site package's pandas I execute `import pandas as pd`, when I want to use my_proj pandas, than I use `from my_proj import pandas as mypd`.

But, now in ssh.py I need site package's pandas (not my_proj pandas).
If in ssh.py I use `import pandas as pd`, pycharm imports `my_proj/src/my_proj/pandas.py` instead of the pandas from site packages.

One solution would be to rename my_proj's pandas.py to something else, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Is there another option to prevent loading library from current directory and import it from site packages?

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

At the end I will use the following procedure:

```
import sys
old_syspath = sys.path
sys.path = [path for path in sys.path if 'customspace' not in path]

import pandas as pd
sys.path = old_syspath
```

Basically, I am removing 'customspace' from  sys.path, than importing pandas and puting sys.path back as it was.

I think this is minimal change and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could tell python exactly what directory to pull pandas from.  EX from my_proj/src/my_proj/ssh import pandas.

Comment: actualy I need something like import site-packages.pandas as pd